# How can a function be "transparently augmented" in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

## Situation

I have function `f`, which I want to augment with function `g`, resulting in function named `h`.

### Definitions

By "augment", in the *general case*, I mean: transform either input (one or more arguments) or output (return value) of function `f`.

By "augment", in the *specific case*, (specific to my current situation) I mean: transform only the output (return value) of function `f` while leaving all the arguments intact.

By "transparent", in the context of "augmentation", (both the *general case* and the *specific case*) I mean: To couple `g`'s implementation as loosely to `f`'s implementation as possible.

### Specific case

In my current situation, this is what I need to do:

`h a b c = g $ f a b c`

I am interested in rewriting it to something like this:

`h = g . f -- Doesn't type-check.`

Because from the perspective of `h` and `g`, it doesn't matter what arguments `f` take, they only care about the return value, hence it would be tight coupling to mention the arguments in any way. For instance, if `f`'s argument count changes in the future, `h` will also need to be changed.

#### So far

I asked lambdabot on the #haskell IRC channel: `@pl h a b c = g $ f a b c` to which I got the response:

`h = ((g .) .) . f`

Which is still not good enough since the number of `(.)`'s is dependent on the number of `f`'s arguments.

### General case

I haven't done much research in this direction, but `erisco` on #haskell pointed me towards http://matt.immute.net/content/pointless-fun which hints to me that a solution for the *general case* could be possible.

#### So far

Using the functions defined by Luke Palmer in the above article this seems to be an equivalent of what we have discussed so far:

`h = f $. id ~> id ~> id ~> g`

However, it seems that this method sadly also suffers from being dependent on the number of arguments of `f` if we want to transform the return value of `f` -- just as the previous methods.

## Working example

In JavaScript, for instance, it is possible to achieve transparent augmentation like this:

`function h () { return g(f.apply(this, arguments)) }`

## Question

How can a function be "transparently augmented" in Haskell?

I am mainly interested in the *specific case*, but it would be also nice to know how to handle the *general case*.

Comment: Assume it is possible, then what should be the type of `h`? Should it not that depends on the type of `f`?

Comment: @LeeDuhem Yes, the type of `h` will be *based on* `f`, except the return value, which will be the type of the return value of `g`.

Comment: @LeeDuhem Like this: `f :: ... -> a {- we don't care/don't know what is in '...' -}`,
`g :: a -> b`, and
`h :: ... -> b {- '...' is the same as for f -}`

Comment: `h` needs a type, so that `...` get to be something. Although you could express with type variable the meaning that "I do not care what the specific type is", there is no way, as far as I know, in Haskell to express that I do not care how many parameters there are.

Comment: You you make explicit the implcit parentheses in a multi-argument function's type, then try and apply your elipsis notation, you'll see why it is so hard.  (The elipsis doesn't capture the right-parens.)  E.g. `a -> b -> c -> d ~ a -> (b -> (c -> d))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, technically, with just enough [IncoherentInstances](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap) you can do pretty much anything:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies,
  FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances #-}

class Augment a b f h where
   augment :: (a -> b) -> f -> h

instance (a ~ c, h ~ b) => Augment a b c h where
   augment = ($)

instance (Augment a b d h', h ~ (c -> h')) => Augment a b (c -> d) h where
   augment g f = augment g . f

-- Usage
t1 = augment not not
r1 = t1 True

t2 = augment (+1) (+)
r2 = t2 2 3

t3 = augment (+1) foldr
r3 = t3 (+) 0 [2,3]
```

Comment: If we were to put the class and the two instances into its own module and only export the `augment` function, would it be safe to import it and use it in other modules? By safe, I mean: would it be reliable or would it have weird and unexpected corner cases? I like it very much that this way you don't have to list the types the way you have to with @hammar's answer, but I am a little cautious to rely on a language pragma with incoherent in the name. **Long question short: Is this a leaky abstraction?**

Comment: @Wizek Personally I don't see why it would be 'leaky' If only `augment` function is exported.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough and a little safer to use the `OverlappingInstances` pragma as @monocell pointed out?

Answer (score 5):

You can sort-of do it, but since there is no way to specify a behavior for everything that *isn't* a function, you'll need a lot of trivial instances for all the other types you care about.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DefaultSignatures #-}

class Augment a where
  type Result a
  type Result a = a

  type Augmented a r
  type Augmented a r = r

  augment :: (Result a -> r) -> a -> Augmented a r

  default augment :: (a -> r) -> a -> r
  augment g x = g x

instance Augment b => Augment (a -> b) where
  type Result (a -> b) = Result b
  type Augmented (a -> b) r = a -> Augmented b r

  augment g f x = augment g (f x) 

instance Augment Bool
instance Augment Char
instance Augment Integer
instance Augment [a]

-- and so on for every result type of every function you want to augment...
```

Example:

```
> let g n x ys = replicate n x ++ ys
> g 2 'a' "bc"
"aabc"
> let g' = augment length g
> g' 2 'a' "bc"
4
> :t g
g :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
> :t g'
g' :: Int -> a -> [a] -> Int
```

Comment: Could closed type families be used to clean this up further on GHC 7.8?

Comment: I have a similar question to you as I had to @Ed'ka: If we were to put the class and the instances into its own module and only export the augment function (and the Augment class?), would it be safe to import it and use it in other modules? By safe, I mean: would it be reliable or would it have weird and unexpected corner cases? I like that you are not relying on the IncoherentInstances pragma, but of course there is the drawback of having to specify a lot of instances. (We could probably do it the way Data.Default does it...) **Long question short: Is this a leaky abstraction?**

Comment: @Wizek: It's reliable, but it might not work the way you'd want it to if the return type of the function you're augmenting is a type variable, because if that type variable gets instantiated to a function type, it would want to continue augmenting _that_. Basically, the augmentation doesn't stop until it's absolutely sure that there can be no more arguments. This is the biggest difference between doing it this way and using `IncoherentInstances`, because that one might stop early in some cases by choosing the base case instance instead of the recursive function instance.

Comment: @Carl: You could possibly use that for the type families, but you'd still need the instances, so I don't think that would make much of a difference.

Comment: @hammar Could you give an example for the unexpected case?

Comment: @Wizek: For example, `augment (\f x -> f x x) (!!) [(||), (&&)] 0 True` won't work, because it tries to continue augmenting the functions in the list, but you _can_ do `augment not (!!) [(||), (&&)] 0 True False`. A "compose past two arguments" function would work in the first case and a "compose past four arguments" in the second case, but `augment` can never compose past any fewer than all of them, even when the types could tell you that that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Wizek: And the reason I had to implement it like that is sort of the problem you're going to run into with any kind of polymorphic composition function: It's not always unambiguous how many arguments we should compose past.

Comment: @hammar Thank you very much for your answer. I marked Ed'ka's answer as accepted since that works without having to specify instances for all the types. And even if we did gather a list, it is not a particularly nice interface to ask the users of the augment function to specify instances for types we missed. Should you, or (anyone else, for that matter) come up with an even better alternative, post it and I'll reassign the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the real return value of something like `a -> b -> c` isn't 
`c`, but `b -> c`. What you want require some kind of test that tells you if a type *isn't*
a function type. You could enumerate the types you are interested in, but that's not so
nice. I think `HList` solve this problem somehow, look at the [paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/HList-ext.pdf). I managed to understand a bit of the solution with overlapping instances, but the rest goes a bit over my head I'm afraid.

Comment: Isn't it possible somehow to tell if a function is a function, if not at compile time, maybe at runtime?

Comment: I believe waiting would buy you nothing in this case. It is possible to let the type checker to this though, look at the answer from Ed'ka, hammar or the paper i linked to. It just isn't easy or nice.

Comment: The implementation doesn't have to be either easy or nice. If it is ugly, but can be abstracted over perfectly (hmm, what is the opposite term for leaky abstraction?) by putting it into its own module, then I am fine with importing the (reliable) augment function from there.

Comment: I think it should be safe as long as you dont define new instances. Also I belive OverlappingInstances are enough, you might not need Incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works, because its arguments are a sequence, or a list, so there is just one argument, really. In that sense it is the same as a curried version of the functions with a tuple representing the collection of arguments.

In a strongly typed language you need a lot more information to do that "transparently" for a function type - for example, dependent types can express this idea, but require the functions to be of specific types, not a arbitrary function type.

I think I saw a workaround in Haskell that can do this, too, but, again, that works only for specific types, which capture the arity of the function, not *any* function.